# How to override option in aliased command?

Tags: rm, alias, interactive

I have a `rm` aliased:

```
alias rm='rm -i'
```

How can I override the `-i` option when I want to remove a large number of files and I don't want to confirm each deletion?

Comment: Shortest way may be \rm ...

Comment: At least in the GNU coreutils implementation of `rm`, the `-f` flag overrides a previous `-i` flag; so you can simply add `-f` to the (aliased) command

Comment: Unfortunately it turned out that this is **not** a duplicate of a previous question and the question is now blocked against a correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the alias by escaping or quoting the command name, e.g.,

```
\rm foo
"rm" foo
```

Further reading:

- [Bash Shell: Ignore Aliases and Functions When Running A Command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ignore-shell-aliases-functions-when-running-command/)

Answer (score 1):

With `rm`, `-f` overrides `-i` if it comes later on the command line.

Whichever option comes last on the command line will have effect, so you can override an `alias rm='rm -i'` just by using `rm -f`, which will expand to `rm -i -f`.

e.g.

```
$ mkdir rmtest
$ cd rmtest
$ touch a b c d e f
$ alias rm='rm -i'
$ rm *
rm: remove regular empty file 'a'? n
rm: remove regular empty file 'b'? n
rm: remove regular empty file 'c'? n
rm: remove regular empty file 'd'? n
rm: remove regular empty file 'e'? n
rm: remove regular empty file 'f'? n
$ rm -f *
$ ls -l
total 0
$
```

`rm -f -i` will, of course, still prompt you for each file to be deleted.

(this is true for at least GNU `rm`.  haven't tested with other versions).

Comment: `-f` doesn't work on Solaris

Comment: `-f` works on Solaris as defined by the standard.

Comment: @schily No it doesn't work. I have just tried it. It still asks for confirmation of the delete.

Comment: Answering your question would need a longer reply that may only be done in the "answer" form. This can only be done it the question is reopened.